# mssql parent child lookup sql

Tags: sql-server, parent-child

So I have a table similar to this one here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea557/1 
This is a small part of a larger complex sql. My desired out needs to be something like

```
ParentId | TopChildId | AllChild     | Priority
--------------------------------------------
  10     |   541      | 345, 541     | 2
  12     |   125      | 123, 124,125 | 3
  13     |   103      | 103, 104     | 2
  14     |   161      | 161          | 1
```

I hope it makes sense. So in a single row, I want to see the parentID, Child ID with the largest priority number and in a column, list all the child id's concatenated.

Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Fiddle is in mySQL... question indicates this is SQL-Server...

Comment: sorry, didn't notice that. Changed it to MSSql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `CID` with the top `priority`, you can use `ROW_NUMBER`. To get the concatenated `CID`s of each `PID`, you can use `FOR XML PATH`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea5574/1/0)

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY priority DESC)
    FROM ParChi
)
SELECT
    ParentID = c.PID,
    TopChildId = c.CID,
    x.AllChild,
    c.priority
FROM Cte c
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CID)
        FROM ParChi
        WHERE PID = c.PID
        ORDER BY priority
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1, 2, '') AS AllChild
) x
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ParentID
```

Comment: So I just learned about another table where I need to collect some more data and looks like that table has the hierarchy already. I rebuilt my table in sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7092e/1 the new table AllProd2 is a close representation of my data. So if I were to do the same thing on this table and get the row with the max priority while displaying the other child id's?

Comment: so I have something strange happening. This works fine in the tables I have in sqlfiddle, but when I try the same code against my actual tables, the AllChild only pulls up the top child! any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.PID AS ParentId , MAX(p.CID) AS TopChildId, temp.AllChild, MAX(p.priority) 
FROM ParChi p
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' +  pc.CID 
    FROM ParChi pc          
    WHERE pc.PID = p.PID
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '') AS AllChild   
)AS temp
GROUP BY p.PID ORDER BY p.PID
```

Comment: Thanks Mayuri. This sql keep erroring out for me, However the answer Felix posted work. Thanks so much for your help.